# Resistance measurement to voltage trigger

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, relay, resistance

I am looking for a circuit that will take a resistance change that comes from detecting the presence of a dilute salt solution and converting it to a 5 volt trigger signal. The resistance changes from open to 12 kohms. I would like the circuit to output a 5 volt signal once this resistance (~12 kohm) is detected.

Comment: Have you considered making that “resister” part of a voltage divider circuit? Then you have a voltage to detect.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot have an applied voltage going through this "resistor" for a voltage divider circuit.  It will be detrimental to the ultimate measurement (electrochemical) I have to make.

Comment: @cucumber There's no way you could detect a resistance change without some voltage across the resistance. That's the fundamental property of resistance, R = U/I, you need U (voltage) and I (current) to find resistance.

Comment: You can avoid most electrochemical effects using an AC voltage with a voltage divider.

Comment: You can also greatly reduce any electrochemical effects by ensuring the current is very small; also if compatible with your other constraints, by measuring infrequently (such as for 1ms every 10 seconds)

Comment: I used an online voltage divider calculator and found: Vin 9v; R1 9.6 kohm; R2 (solution) 12 kohm; Vout across R2 5v.  I did a calculation of the circuit current and I got 0.45 mA.  Seems kind of high.  Would I need a rapid triggering device to prevent an electrochemical reaction?  I am not sure I can use AC, the instrument calls for 5 volts as a trigger, and I assumed it was DC.  I would also need an AC-to-DC converter if I use AC, correct?

Comment: Can you write an Arduino program, that produces a 200 Hz square wave signal and takes an ADC measurement at each rising and falling edge of the square wave? With that you would be half the way through it.

Comment: @cucumber Only you can tell us what's acceptable and what's not for the electrochemical process you are working with. But measurement affects the measured. So how better to mitigate that impact is up to you to say. Not us. That said, resistance measurement will require the movement of charge. It cannot be helped. It can be designed. But it cannot be avoided. So you need to tell us what, how often, under what circumstances, etc.  That's a specification that comes from you, not from us.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a comparator. Please draw a schematic of what you have and what you need your mystery box to output.

Comment: @cucumber Measurement is complicated. For example, charges and potential barriers may arise on the surface and near measuring electrodes and for that and also to perhaps eliminate influences of electrode polarization resistance and non-linear ion dynamics effects, novel ideas may require exploration. But we would not have any idea about that. We are just ignorant slobs capable of barely more than knowing the difference between one resistor value and another. This is your domain. Your territory. Tell us about it.

Comment: @cucumber I didn't know about this until today, but there's papers on *"non-contact conductometry"*. You might study some papers on this topic and tell us what you uncover that may relate to your situation. I had no idea. Now I do. But again, this is for you to evaluate an an approach.